# Subtracting from COALESCE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL query which look something like this:

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(field1, 0) AS field1, 
COALESCE(field2, 0) AS field2,
COALESCE(field3 - field1 - field2, 0) AS field
FROM ...

However the problem with it is that given say:

field1 = 1
field2 = 0
field3 = 2
```

When the output is displayed, field3 shows 0, despite 2 - 1 - 0 = 1.

COALESCE is used as I'm left outer joining a few tables which might result in Null values.

And in the event if field3 is null, would I have any problems too?

Thank you

Comment: try ifnull function..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do the coalesce independently:

```
SELECT COALESCE(field1, 0) AS field1, COALESCE(field2, 0) AS field2,
       COALESCE(field3, 0) - coalesce(field1, 0) - coalesce(field2, 0) AS field
FROM ...
```

As for your example, I suspect that `field2` is actually `NULL` and not 0.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the alias given on the same level for calculation. You need to repeat again the function or just wrap the primary computation in a subquery,

```
SELECT  field1, field2,
        field3 - (field1 + field2)
FROM
        (
            SELECT  COALESCE(field1, 0) AS field1, 
                    COALESCE(field2, 0) AS field2, 
                    COALESCE(field3, 0) field3
            FROM    TableName
        ) x
```

The reason is because the Order of SQL Operation is as follow:

- FROM clause
- WHERE clause
- GROUP BY clause
- HAVING clause
- SELECT clause
- ORDER BY clause

`ALIAS` are given on `SELECT` statement and are not accessible on the level they were created.